# Is a line in a Java program the same thing as a statement?

Tags: java, lines, statements

I'm a Java noob. I've only used it for a few days and I'm still trying to figure it all out. In a program, is a line the same thing as a statement?

Comment: So many answers... Which one do I accept?

Comment: Accept the one that works for you.

Comment: The one that is most helpful to you. If they are all equally helpful, typically the first answer posted is accepted.

Comment: @Benny Make a program and use `Random` to let the program chooses the one you will accept ;)

Comment: Accept the oldest edited answer which most closely clears your doubt.

Comment: LOL. @Matt Ball Which one was posted first?

Comment: @Benny hover your mouse over the "answered X mins ago" to see the timestamp. I think it was mine...

Comment: @Matt Ball I've done that, and it is indeed your answer. However, I'm now debating between fireshadow's answer and yours. I sure wish I could accept two... :(

Comment: @Matt Ball I've accepted fireshadow's answer, but as soon as I can upvote I will upvote yours. :)

Comment: Voting up requires 15 rep: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up ...there you go `:)`

Comment: @Matt Ball Is there a bug in the system? It says `Please login or register to vote for this post` and doesn't let me upvote. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3576/discussion-between-matt-ball-and-benny)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The Java compiler doesn't look at lines, spacing, or other formatting issues when compiling a program. It just wants to see the `;` at the end of each **statement**. This **line** would work just fine:

```
int i = 13; i += 23;
```

However, doing things like this can--and most likely will--cause readability issues with the source code. For this reason, it isn't recommended.

It is also possible for a single statement to span multiple lines:

```
int i =
    13;
```

Answer (score 5):

No. I can write:

```
int x = 1; int y = 2;
```

That's one line, and two statements.

Answer (score 4):

> In a program, is a line the same thing as a statement?

No.

Want to know the difference? Start with the [JLS §14.5: Blocks and Statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.5):

> ```
> Statement:
>         StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
>         LabeledStatement
>         IfThenStatement
>         IfThenElseStatement
>         WhileStatement
>         ForStatement
>
> StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
>         Block
>         EmptyStatement
>         ExpressionStatement
>         AssertStatement
>         SwitchStatement
>         DoStatement
>         BreakStatement
>         ContinueStatement
>         ReturnStatement
>         SynchronizedStatement
>         ThrowStatement
>         TryStatement
>
> StatementNoShortIf:
>         StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
>         LabeledStatementNoShortIf
>         IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf
>         WhileStatementNoShortIf
>         ForStatementNoShortIf
> ```

Answer (score 4):

According to [Java grammar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/syntax.doc.html):

```
Statement:
    Block
    if ParExpression Statement [else Statement]
    for ( ForInitOpt   ;   [Expression]   ;   ForUpdateOpt ) Statement
    while ParExpression Statement
    do Statement while ParExpression   ; 
    try Block ( Catches | [Catches] finally Block )
    switch ParExpression { SwitchBlockStatementGroups }
    synchronized ParExpression Block
    return [Expression] ; 
    throw Expression   ; 
    break [Identifier]
    continue [Identifier]
    ; 
    ExpressionStatement
    Identifier   :   Statement
```

Based on this you can easily see that one statement can span multiple lines but also single line can host multiple statements. Also note that *statement* is a very broad term.

Comment: Just a heads up, that's not the most recent version of the JLS.

Answer (score 2):

This line includes two statements:

```
j = 5; j += 3;
```

So, a line is not necessarily a statement...

Answer (score 2):

Only by common practice, and for readability. In Java statements are terminated with semicolons, or in the case of blocks, by pairs of curlybraces ( { } ).